# Mysql очень сложный запрос

Tags: mysql, mysqli

На текущий момент запрос такого вида

```
SELECT id, product1, (
    SELECT price2
    FROM post_2 
    WHERE UPPER(post_2.post2) 
    LIKE concat('%',UPPER(product1),'%') 
    AND price2 > 0) 
FROM parser 
WHERE product1 
IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID
```

в таблице parser есть столбец с названиями товара
в таблице post_2 столбец post2 это название товара поставщика а столбец price2 это столбец с ценой на его товар ... не могу составить правильный запрос для поиска товара из значений первой таблицы и извлечения соответствующей цены ... Помогите пожалуйста ...

Comment: лучше образцы данных приветите и более точное описание таблиц. И в данных обязательно отразите много ли записей в price2 для одного значения из parser, потому как подзапрос в списке выборки должен гарантированно возвращать одну строку не больше и не меньше. по текущему описанию ничего не понятно

Comment: есть основная таблица "parser" с индексом по "id" и столбцом "product1"  со списком товара , есть таблица "post_2" где находятся в столбце "post2" названия товара а в столбце "price2" цена на него . мне нужно составить запрос для поиска товара в таблице "post_2" по значению "product1" из таблицы parser и в результате получить соответствующую ему цену из столбца "price2" таблицы "post_2"

Comment: ну так тут же у вас именно это и написано

Comment: а какие еще нужны данные для формирования запроса ??? я напишу

Comment: Сейчас `WHERE UPPER(post_2.post2) LIKE concat('%',UPPER(product1),'%') ` ищет название товара из product1 в post2 таблицы post_2, т.е. именно то, что вы просите. поэтому и непонятно что же вы хотите, в отличие от того что он уже делает. В идеале напишите в вопросе пару строк из одной и другой таблицы и что запрос из этих строк должен получить на выходе

Answer (score 2):

вот в принципе сам код

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('allow_url_fopen','1');//разрешаем открывать адреса
    ini_set('output_buffering','1');//output_buffering = On
    set_time_limit(0);//убираем лимит времени

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "parser", "parser", "parser");//подключаем бвзу данных
```

```
$query = "SELECT id, product1 FROM parser WHERE product1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID";//запрос
$result = $mysqli->query($query);//выполнение запроса   

$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array())//ассоциативный массив
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
foreach($rows as $row)//перебор массива
{
    $Id = $row['id'];//индекс
    $Product1 = $row['product1'];//название продукта

    $post   = "SELECT price2 FROM post_2 WHERE UPPER(post2) LIKE '%".strtoupper($Product1)."%' AND price2 > 0 LIMIT 1";
    $Price1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($post)) or die("Запрос ошибочный");
    $Price2 = mysqli_fetch_row($Price1) or die("ошибочн0");
    $Price = $Price2['price2'];


    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE parser SET post1_price = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $Price, $Id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close(); 
    echo "$Id - $Product1 - $Price<br>";
}</code>
```

но он не хочет работать ... выборка id и product1 идет а вот с price нет